How to reinstal Ubuntu using USB in dual boot?
I was using Ubuntu 22.04 in my Dell XPS 13 as dual boot and recently I was trying to update the version to 24.04. It was showing that few packages are broken and it can't update. First I tried fixing the broken package but it didn't worked and then I unistalled those packages and tried installing them again. Then I wasn't seeing Software app in the Ubuntu so I used command line to update the Ubuntu version hoping it will fix all the broken packages while updating to the new version but somehow I end up updated to Ubuntu 23.10 and Wifi drivers are missing. I can't update the Ubuntu version now.
How can I fix this issue and go back to Ubuntu 22.04 or update to Ubuntu 24.04 without loosing any data? What are my options here?

Can you boot to grub menu? And run fixes from there? Otherwise, you will need live installer flash drive.  If only Ubuntu, you have to press escape key just after UEFI/BIOS vendor logo screen & before grub menu normally appears. Cannot go back, unless you have full backup. I typically suggest just backing up /home, list of installed apps, maybe /etc if you edit system files (I edit grub but save copies to /home for backup). If you install server apps - database, web, etc those also require backup from / (root).

@oldfred I used USB Tethering to connect to the internet and using the command line I tried updating the Ubuntu version and the process went well. But now I'm not able to get past the Ubuntu loading screen. Kernel is now updated from 5.15.0-78 to 6.11.0-7 and it shows the warning EFI stub WARNING: Failed to measure data for event 1: 0*0000000000b

How did you get 6.11? I am using 24.04.1 and have kernel 6.8. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
